# Monitoring events in a parent window when a child window is open in Qt

Tags: qt, events, kiosk, childwindow, kiosk-mode

I'm trying to auto-hide the mouse in my application after a few seconds of inactivity and have the code below to handle this.  Everything works great *until* I open a child window: the mouse does not reappear until I move the mouse over the child window.  If I monitor all of the events in MyMainWindow::eventFilter(), I do not see any events for the parent window while the child window is open.  I thought `qApp->installEventFilter()` added the event filter for *all* windows of an application.  Thoughts?

My platform is Windows 7 and Qt 4.8.  The application runs full screen on a kiosked computer -- i.e., there is nothing else running on the computer except my application.

```
MyMainWindow::MyMainWindow( QWidget *parent ) :
    QMainWindow( parent ),
    ui( new Ui::MyMainWindow )
{
    // all the other setup...
    hideMouseTimer.start( HideMouseDelay_ms );
    connect( &hideMouseTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(hideMouseTimerExpiry()) );

    if( qApp )
    {
        qApp->installEventFilter( this );
    }
}

bool MyMainWindow::eventFilter( QObject *obj, QEvent *event )
{
   /*
    * Monitor mouse movement. If the mouse has been hidden, show it and start
    * the timer for the next check for hiding it.
    */
   if( event->type() == QEvent::MouseMove )
   {
       qApp->restoreOverrideCursor();
       hideMouseTimer.start( HideMouseDelay_ms );
   }

   return QWidget::eventFilter( obj, event ); 
}

void MyMainWindow::hideMouseTimerExpiry()
{
    qApp->setOverrideCursor( QCursor( Qt::BlankCursor ) );
    hideMouseTimer.stop();
}

void MyMainWindow::on_dialog_clicked()
{
    myDiaglog *d = new myDialog();
    d->exec();
    delete d;
}
```

Comment: Is this the complete code? Your event filter doesn't return a value. And is the dialog the "child window" you are referring to?

Comment: @jmk No, it's not the complete code but just what I thought were the relevant parts.  I added the return statement to the event filter. Yes, the child window is the dialog.